# When I re-open a project why don't I see the MVC subfolders in the Project Explorer anymore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, aptana3

I'm learning Ruby on Rails, using Aptana 3 on Windows7 as my IDE. I created my first project as part of a tutorial. But now when I try to go back and study the MVC files that were generated they don't appear in the project explorer or app explorer windows like they did when I created my project. Am I doing something wrong? Perhaps I didn't enter the correct path when Apatana prompted me for my workspace name? How can I know what workspace I originally used when I set up the project?

Thank you for helping out a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What U need to do is

1>go to project explorer (right side of app.explorer),if not available then go to windows menu>show views>Project explorer and locate your application

2>then right click on its name(Main Application's name) and click on Promote to Project (by doing this a popup menu will open)

3>First of all enable the check box Rails, then same for ruby and then uncheck the box for Web- Primary and click on Finish

Now navigate to your App. tab , you can see you application with all of its folder

[P.S. stretch aptana's screen after you click on finish button to menu bar :D as I think I think aptana has that problem by default ]

Hope It helped !!!